# Скрывать данные в google sheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть google таблица, доступ к которой есть у нескольких пользователей. Как можно скрывать данные пользователей от других пользователей. Все данные должен видеть только я. Это возможно реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Не вполне логично "скрывать" данные от пользователя, которому уже предоставлен доступ к таблице как минимум на чтение данных. С другой стороны, обычно в этом и нет необходимости, поскольку "секретные" данные всегда можно вынести в другую таблицу, а связать данные из разных таблиц можно скриптом, имеющим необходимые права доступа.

Не следует хранить все данные в одной таблице, если требуется разграничить доступ к ним.